# Flutter web keyboard scrolling not working with non default scrollcontroller

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have following widget:

```
Scrollbar(
    isAlwaysShown: true,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
            children: [],
        ),
    ),
),
```

With the default scroll controller the widget scrolls using both scrollbar and keyboard.
But when I add a scrollcontroller, widget scrolls only using scrollbar but it does not responds to keyboard keys.

```
Scrollbar(
    isAlwaysShown: true,
    controller: _scrollController,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        child: Column(
            children: [],
        ),
    ),
),
```

Can someone please point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
 ScrollController scollBarController = ScrollController();



 Scrollbar(
              controller: scollBarController,
              isAlwaysShown: true,
              showTrackOnHover: true,
                 
child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      controller: scollBarController,
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering arises from the way you're assigning the same scroll controller to both the Scrollbar and the SingleChildScrollView. When you provide the same scroll controller to both widgets, it essentially ties their scrolling behaviors together, causing conflicts in handling scrolling events from different sources like the scrollbar and keyboard.

To resolve this, you need to use separate ScrollController instances for the Scrollbar and the SingleChildScrollView. Here's how you can correct your code:

```
ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

...

Scrollbar(
  isAlwaysShown: true,
  controller: _scrollController,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [],
    ),
  ),
),
```

By doing this, the Scrollbar and SingleChildScrollView will each have their own independent ScrollController, allowing them to handle scrolling events from the scrollbar and keyboard separately. This should enable the widget to respond to both scrollbar interaction and keyboard scrolling.